What bracket should I use to wall mount a floor fan?
I have this 18" High velocity floor fan.

I need to mount it on the wall so that it is out of the way of tiny fingers. I am in England so I will be drilling into brick. Strength and functionality is more important than aesthetics, as I do not want it to fall on tiny heads.
What bracket do I need?
I found the Ruck® RS 100 - 160 inline tube fan mounting bracket 245 mm - MRS 1 but I am not sure if that is the right thing.
I feel like 3 x heavy duty versions of a pipe clip would do the job, but I cannot see any that look strong enough.

I have a similar fan which I wall- mounted using a pair of 3/4" conduit straps (screwed into studs).

Do you need it to be functional or aesthetically pleasing? What does your wall look like? Regardless, do NOT use those precarious drywall anchors for something which produces vibration or else it will fail spectacularly. Make sure to hit studs.

@MonkeyZeus I have updated the question. In short, function over form.

Your clips will be strong enough.  The issue will be mounting them to the brick wall.  There are many types of masonry anchors that would suffice, but their reliability depends entirely on proper installation.  Unless I underestimate your experience with masonry anchors, I would advise you to have it done professionally. The pro will know what to use to install the fan properly.

You need to mitigate the vibration from the fan to your mounting points.
Get some 28 Ga. Galvanized Hanger Strap like this:

And mount the fan to your wall like this:


Perhaps some rubber mat or similar material between the fan frame and the strap? To act as a vibration dampener.

The OP states will be drilling into brick, not studs.  Solid mounting to masonry is critical.  Vibration damping is not necessarily needed, given OP has not indicated the fan blades are seriously out of balance.  The accent is on the wrong syllable.
